# No converter found capable of converting from type

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [com.skywarelabs.runwayreporting.api.modules.asset.Asset] to type [com.skywarelabs.runwayreporting.api.modules.asset.AssetPageView]

I have two repository methods which do essentialy the same thing.
I'm expecting them to return an object of <Page>.
If I call findPageByAerodrome, this works correctly.
However, If I call findPageByFilter, I get the error below.
..the reason I want to use findPageByFilter is that I wish to extend this with additional filtering parameters.

'''
public interface AssetRepository extends PageCrudRepository<Asset, Long> {

```
@Query("SELECT a FROM Asset a WHERE " +
        "(a.aerodrome = :aerodrome)")
<T> Page<T> findPageByFilter(@Param("aerodrome") Aerodrome aerodrome,
                             Pageable pageable, Class<T> type);

<T> Page<T> findPageByAerodrome(@Param("aerodrome") Aerodrome aerodrome,
                                Pageable pageable, Class<T> type);
```

,,,

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead

```java
<T> Page<T> findAll(Specification s, Pageable pageable, Class<T> type);
```

and pass a custom `Specification` where you create your equality filter like this:

```java
<T> Page<T> findPageByFilter(@Param("aerodrome") Aerodrome aerodrome,
                             Pageable pageable, Class<T> type) {
  return findAll(
    new Specification() {
      @Override
      public Predicate toPredicate(Root<T> root, CriteriaQuery query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
        return cb.equal(root.get("aerodrome"), aerodrome);
      }
    },
    pageable,
    type
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  I need to add an entity specific constructor.

'''
public AssetPageView(Asset asset) {
this ( asset.getId(), asset.getAssetType(), asset.getAerodrome(), asset.getName(),
asset.getAreaOfOperationsLoc(), asset.getDisplayOrder() );
}

```
public AssetPageView(Long id, AssetType assetType, Aerodrome aerodrome, String name,
                     String areaOfOperationsLoc, Long displayOrder) {
    this.id = id;
    this.assetType = assetType.getName();
    this.aerodrome = aerodrome.getCallSign();
    this.name = name;
    this.areaOfOperationsLoc = areaOfOperationsLoc;
    this.displayOrder = displayOrder;
}
```

'''